# List of undervalued questions since 2016

Tags: discussion, questions, up-votes

I'm hoping that over time we can create a positivity feedback loop ("[pay it forward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pay_it_forward)" style) on this site by upvoting one another's (worthy) content.  This post is an attempt to stating the feedback look.

[image: Be excellent to each other]

To encourage users to post worthwhile content, we need to upvote it ("not downvoting" is not enough).  Users need to get the impression that if they put in the effort, it's appreciated through upvoting.

> It is imperative that beta users cast as many of their 30 daily votes as they can. -- [Robert Cartaino](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/21/when-will-my-site-graduate/), Director of Community Development, 2010

As a step towards this end, this post is aimed at identifying undervalued questions (perhaps I'll make a similar posts for answers later), and hopefully this will attract more upvotes to them in particular.  None are 100% perfect (no question is), but when I see them, I think *this could be answered*.

---

Here's the list (none are my own questions):

January 2016 (search [`is:question created:2016-01 score:1`](https://islam.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion%20created%3A2016-01%20score%3A1)):

- [Is Jesus considered to be the messiah in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/29691/17163)
- [Is Adam's Peak a sacred place for Muslims?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/29342/17163)
- [Are Muslim women allowed to marry revert Muslims?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/29629/17163)

February 2016:

- [Why is the prayer or dua "peace be upon him" used for someone not alive?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/29796/17163)

March 2016:

- [Is the name “Christine” haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/30189/17163)
- [What will happen to those who are mentally ill in the afterlife?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/30415/17163)
- [Why do we find Medinian verses in Meccan Chapters and vice versa?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/30390/17163)
- [Doesn't Qur'an 47:4 put an end to slavery?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/30587/17163)

April 2016:

- [Is conversion between Islamic denominations considered apostasy?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/30813/17163)
- [What is the definition ties of Kinship?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/30795/17163)

May 2016:

- [Is it compulsory for Imam of a masjid/mosque to have a beard?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/31160/17163)
- [Why did Noah's wife go to hell according to Quran?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/31205/17163)
- [Can women pray in public, like men?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/31172/17163)
- [Is it allowed to call anyone "son" except our own child?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/31303/17163)

June 2016:

- [In what context is the word unseen for jinns used in Qu'ran 34:14?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/33131/17163)
- [What did Allah teach David in Surah Al-Baqarah, Verse 251?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/32710/17163)
- [Is it permissible to wear minimal clothing, exposing awrah, when alone?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/32873/17163)
- [Is sleeping a necessary condition for Tahajjud (night prayer)?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/32516/17163)

July 2016:

- [Are we obliged to reduce prayer when on a journey?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/33493/17163)
- [Are school proms haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/33336/17163)

August 2016:

- [Mustafa vs. Mujtaba. What's the difference?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/34892/17163)

September 2016:

- [Is it okay if I eat at Halal Restaurant that served beer/alcohol?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/35489/17163)
- [Why did the women in Sura 12.30-31 cut their hands when they saw how "beautiful" Joseph was?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/35500/17163)

October 2016:

- [Can Maryam be considered a prophet even though she's a female? Why or why not?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/35768/17163)
- [What is the wisdom behind hiding adultery between spouses?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/35957/17163)
- [How does one go about getting an Islamic divorce in the USA?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36025/17163)
- [Can one do sadaqa (voluntary charity) out of haram income?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/35918/17163)

November 2016:

- [Is it appropriate to use the term "Semite" for Muslims?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36390/17163)
- [Is it ok to remove pork and eat food?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36157/17163)
- [Can a marriage be annulled in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36437/17163)
- [Why do some Muslims fold the top right of their prayer mats?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36385/17163)

December 2016:

- [According to Islamic sources, did Aisha gave public speeches?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36606/17163)
- [Is disbelief in "free will" kufr?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36657/17163)
- [Is it acceptable to perform istakhara in English? If so, how?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36674/17163)

January 2017:

- [What is the meaning of hadith grading "Sahih in Chain"?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/37206/17163)

February 2017:

- [Is fearing that one would discover Islam to be untrue kufr of doubt?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/37783/17163)
- [If someone is caught stealing food but another person pays for it, is there still a punishment?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/38089/17163)
- [Did Umar (RA) say, "A man should be like a child with his wives ..."?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/37767/17163)

March 2017:

- [How Islam allow or disallow new innovation and technology?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/38411/17163)

---

I find the most suitable kinds of questions are those requesting a "unit of knowledge".  The question gives a clear-cut goal for an answerer, and it would be easy to recognize an answer that meets that goal.  Once someone gives an answer, the question can be considered "done"; it will have long-term usefulness and can be referenced in the future.

I tend to be generous with upvotes (after all, it's just +5 or +10 internet points)---I tend to think of "upvoting" as the default, and "not upvoting" is my downvoting.  [Other people will have different voting philosophies.  This doesn't make one philosophy "wrong"; in fact, this imbalance is necessary, as it results in different posts getting different scores.]

---

And, finally, perhaps the reader would like to highlight some questions they think are undervalued?